# On hold (Too Broad) but only has one valid answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, self-answer, on-hold

This [Animating in Graphics Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003457/how-do-i-animate-a-property-that-my-framework-and-libraries-dont-support-animat) was put on hold for being too broad. But over the years I've seen (and sought) the same type answer to this same type of question  in regards to linear interpolation animations. I believe it has a single specific answer which I gave. Is this question really too broad or did the moderator just not like how I tried to answer my own question?

This was a question I asked for many years and finally arrived at a solution. I also see many other people ask the same question. Please read the post and let me know what you think.

I'd like to find a way to post this question and answer pair so that people in my previous position can find a solution. If I didn't setup my self-answer correctly, how can I fix this?

Comment: At a glance, it might have something to do with having two questions in one: _"what do all GUI animations have in common? And How could I animate anything in the GUI?"_ They seem like two separate questions, the first alone potentially being a list/broad question, so that likely has something to do with it. The size of your answer might have aided in the closure as well, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Kendra So how do I fix it and get off hold. Could I just post it again with the second question only. Or is there anything else I can do.

Comment: My two cents, if your question is about "GUI animations" it should not have the language specific tags like c# and java.  That just seems like casting a net way too wide.

Comment: Thanks @ryanyuyu . Well I am trying to catch people from those languages that have that same problem. Why is that bad or annoying?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I _personally_ would start by editing the first question out. You might be able to keep the answer to it in your answer, as an extra tidbit, if you make sure it's worded to not stick out oddly. Editing it should bump it into the reopen queue. However, taking a closer look, it might still not be enough. Your question shows no attempts at fixing a problem and comes across as a "Gimme teh codez" question, even though you answered it yourself. (Reviewers won't see that.) I don't know _for sure_ if that'll be the case, of course. (I don't have the rep to review/close.)

Comment: Because your question isn't actually about those languages.  For example, I follow both c# and javascript.  Your question hits two of my tags, yet it's two completely separate parts of my job.  And it's not even that relevant to me despite hitting to tags.

Comment: Okay @ryanyuyu, thanks.

Comment: Good thoughts @Kendra. I'll try editing it like that.

Comment: @EricBischoff I'm utterly unconvinced by the "it has a single specific answer" argument. You've decided to approach the topic in a certain way that satisfies you. However, I can readily see people posting answers that deal with animating a rotation, a text string, or a mask, or that deal with things you did not mention, like 3D. Even if the basic principles of doing each of these *are* in your answer, this, by itself, won't block other answers from being posted and remaining, because answers that explain details that earlier answers have not covered *are* welcome on SO.

Comment: @Louis, and with that comment...SO is dead to me. See this article:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers

Comment: @EricBischoff: ... I have no idea what Louis's comment has to do with what you linked to. But I wish you the best in your endeavors.

Comment: The answer looks like a great blog post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that you're rating your question's answer-ability based on the answer you provided rather than the scope of the question you asked.

However much you may feel that your answer is the only right one... it *isn't*. I know that because, while you talk about linear interpolation... what about non-linear interpolation forms? Where's the quadratic or cubic interpoation? At its core, animation is *any function* that returns different values based on time. A linear relationship between time and the return value is only one possible form; it is certainly not "the basis of all animation".

So no, your answer is *not* the only possible correct one.

Your answer provides solid and useful information. But the question is simply too broad for this site.

That doesn't mean the only questions we want are "Plz fix mai cod3z!" questions. But there's a lot of room between that and "How does animation work?"

Comment: Quadratic and cubic are derived from linear and it is a good first step to understand linear. So instead of further describing my "problems". Give me a solution other than "provide solid and useful information". It is solid and useful and you don't understand the context if you think quadratic and cubic interpolations are not based on linear.

Comment: Let's pretend that you're right about linear vs. quadratic and cubic. What about using sinusoidal interpolation between two end-points? What about logarithmic interpolation? Oh, and here's the best part: the fact that we're having this conversation *at all* proves that your question is too broad. If two experts who know a lot about animation cannot agree, then the problem is the question?

Comment: "*Give me a solution*" There is no solution. Your problem is that you want to share certain information. However, the information you want to share does not fit our Q&A format. So you can't share it here. It's more suited to a blog or forum than a focused Q&A setting. It's a dissertation, not a specific question & answer. And while we appreciate the value of a good dissertation, Q&A isn't the place to do that sort of thing. Stack Overflow is not intended to be all things for all people.

Comment: Excellent response and I believe you are right:) I will point out to you that the system is bipolar and it's two moods are community and system. See this link:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Here is a quote from SO:

"it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."

Comment: @EricBischoff: Yes, you are totally allowed to ask and answer your own question. But we don't *suspend the rules* on questions when you do. Your question must still be a focused, legitimate question. Your question here is not.

Comment: Einstein was long discourage for his question about what it would be like to ride on a beam of light. I'm not in the same category with him. The point is that although you may not see it as legitimate as the purveyor of SO behavior, it is a legitimate question.

Comment: @EricBischoff: We're not going to lower our quality standards just because you ask us to. And yes, despite the fact that your answer is good, your *question* is a low-quality one by our standards.

Comment: @EricBischoff You're entirely within your rights to be interested in that information.  You may also be correct in assuming that there are others that are interested in it.  But that doesn't mean it belongs on SO.  SO is not obligated to house all information that anyone on the face of the earth thinks might be valuable.  It's a site with a specific focus, and it works to ensure the content posted here fits within that focus.  Your quesiton doesn't fit within SO's scope.  That doesn't mean it's bad, it just means you need to find somewhere more appropriate to post that content.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, You have adequately helped me understand why it was put on hold. So I'll give you the right answer. But, you havn't answered how asking "What is the basic principle behind animation" is a bad question. And you should rethink your stance about there being animation outside of interpolation. The only example (or almost example) I can think of is extrapolation, which cannot be controlled very well so it's not used to animate.

Comment: Thank you @Servy for the insight.

Comment: @Eric instead of posting self-answered Q&As you may want to go and write a blog about this. I'm sure your writing style and explanations will be appreciated by many.

Comment: @EricBischoff: "*But, you havn't answered how asking "What is the basic principle behind animation" is a bad question.*" Because questions which are overly broad will invariably attract *discussion*. Such as our discussion here about linear and non-linear forms of interpolation. Two experts can reasonably disagree on what the "basic principle" behind something is. SO is not about discussion. We learned long ago that if you want to make sure that discussion is minimized, you have to deal only with *specific* questions, not broad and general ones.

Comment: @EricBischoff: Also, questions which are overly broad frequently have no right answer. You, as the asker, may prefer to believe that linear interpolation is the basic principle of all animation. But my potential answer that all animation is simply any `F(t)` where `t` is time is no less valid than yours. It's simply a different perspective. From an objective perspective, whether one answer is right or not is difficult at best to determine.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Gotcha. I wasn't aware that discussion was discouraged. I would love it (seriously) if you answered my question with your perspective that animation is any `F(t)`! Then I could argue that the function is an interpolation. And the discussion would continue. But I'll let that be the nail in the coffin.  Thanks for taking the time to wrestle over this with me. Btw, I'm also impressed with your work. You should answer more graphics question.

Comment: @EricBischoff: One of the benefits of SO is that it helps to remove the non-discussion type questions from forums and puts them in a place where they can be dealt with. That leaves forums and so forth as the place to go for actual discussion. "*You should answer more graphics question.*" I don't think I can [answer more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A734069+%5Bopengl). There are only so many hours in the day.

Comment: @NicolBolas, Oh wow.